# How to cancel Task C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I have a Task which retrieves some data from a Web Service. The Webservice should only get called when I open a page (this is Xamarin.Forms) and it should only run if there isn't another version of the task running - This part works fine.

When I move away from the page, I want to cancel the Task - I can't seem to get that piece working. When `OnAppearing()`, `OnDisappearing()`, `OnAppearing() is hit before the webservice returns the data, logs just write "Task has attempted to start..." which means that the Task didn't get cancelled. Instead the task should have been cancelled when`OnDisappearing()` was called.

I have tried to follow some of the examples posted on StackOverflow but doesn't seem to work and I can't quite figure it out.

The code I have is below:

OnAppearing:

```
private Task task;
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (task != null && (task.Status == TaskStatus.Running || task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun || task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task has attempted to start while already running");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task has began");

        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {

            await GetDataAsync();
            /* EDIT: This is what I originally posted, but doesn't work so have commented it out
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await GetDataAsync();
            }
             */
       }, token);
   }      
}
```

OnDisappearing:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    Debug.WriteLine("Page dissapear");
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task Cancelled");
}
```

GetData Method

```
public async Task GetData()
{
    WebAPI api = new WebAPI();

    try
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            PageLoading();
        });

        string r = await api.GetProfileStatus(token);
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
           if (r == "OK")
           {
                GetDataSuccess();
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        // log exception
     }
}
```

Comment: Where does GetData get the token? Is it the same as above it?

Comment: @Steve properly space your code next time, it make it more readable

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm not sure. I thought that the token passed in "Task.Run(async () =>..." is the token? Not very familiar with this really.

Comment: @johnny5 OK noted - thanks will do.

Comment: Remove the `Task.Run` - it is uneccessary because GetData(Async) is already async so there's no need to wrap it in another task - and provide GetData(Async) with the cancellation token. How and if the cancellation works depends on how GetProfileStatus is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the right check in a wrong place:

```
var token = tokenSource.Token;
task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await GetDataAsync();
    }
}
```

Here you start the task, and after that start it again and again in a loop. The right thing to do is check the token inside your `GetData`, and futher to `api` variable, if possible. In this case you'll be able to cancel the service call as you need.

Side notes:

- make your event handlers `async`, and do not wrap your work in `Task.Run`
- make your `GetData` `Task<T>` so you can actually return status to the calling code, then you can remove `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, as `await` will restore the context after async operation

So your code will be something like this:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (task != null && (task.Status == TaskStatus.Running || task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun || task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task has attempted to start while already running");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task has began");

        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        PageLoading();
        var r = await GetDataAsync(token);
        if (r == "OK")
        {
            GetDataSuccess();
        }
   }      
}

public async Task GetDataAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    WebAPI api = new WebAPI();
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    try
    {
        return await api.GetProfileStatus(token);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log exception and return error
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this! I will give it a go and see how it works out. I'm not sure if OnAppearing can be marked as async as it is inherited from Xamarin.Forms so that's why I had used Task.Run.

Comment: Looks like this did work and changing OnAppearing to async as well - thanks.

Comment: `async` isn't a part of signature for methods, and `async void` is exactly and only for event handlers :)